# Adding Chatter to an LWC Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, chatter

I have a composite LWC component which has several child LWC components and I would like to add a Chatter feed related to my SObject (Account in this case) as another child, and be able to pass in my object Id.

I cannot find any docs on how to do this.

Alternately, I would like to see an example on how to compose the LWC components and the Chatter feed within App Builder and be able to pass the Account Id to Chatter that way.

Comment: There is no LWC component yet for a chatter feed but there is one for Aura (`forceChatter:feed`). Are you against using an aura component and your composite LWC side by side with some communication between the two?

Comment: That would work @MarkPond

Comment: Incidentally, I ended up building a custom LWC based Chatter UX.  It doesn't have the full functionality of the native Chatter UX but it definitely offers the core capabilities interfacing with the native Chatter backend.  I will post a link to a repo if folks are interested.

Comment: Hey Shane, id be very curious to see your custom component if you are willing to share.

Comment: @ShaneK did you manage to build the chatter component? If so, I'd like to take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: @Shanerk I'm keen to see this component too if you had it ready to show.